# Including Open-Source 3rd-party JARs in your public GIT Repositories

Tags: java, git, maven, jar

I'd like to ask about the best practices / legal way on how to include 3rd party open source JARs in my own project in a public GIT Repository.  Let's say I have a project which has JARs like commons-lang3 in my lib, can I just commit the JAR into the lib folder as-is or do I have to go through some special process and include extra license files, etc., for the whole process to be correct?  Another alternative is I can just include the POM file, and anyone can build it using Maven and download all the dependencies themselves, but I still would like to know about the best practices/correct process for this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: These days, please just use Maven and the artifacts at Maven Central.

Answer (score 0):

Maven approach would be fine. If there are any License with your 3rd party library, include them in to the project as well.